VBA lock column if cell equals specific value
I need VBA to check a column's header (cell in row 6), if it equals "Actual" - entire column must be locked for editing.
If cell equals "Forecast", column must not be locked.
At the moment my code locks columns even if they have another header.
I checked headers' formats, it's Text.
Please help if you have any ideas on what the issue might be:
Dim Sh As Worksheet
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Sh.Unprotect Password:="1" 
    Sh.Cells.Locked = False

**On Error Resume Next

For Each Sh In Worksheets(Array("1", "2"))
    Dim m As Long
    For m = 7 To 37
        If Sh.Range(Columns(6, m)) = "Actual" Then
        Sh.Columns(m).Locked = True
        ElseIf Sh.Range(Columns(6, m)) = "Forecast" Then
        Sh.Columns(m).Locked = False
    End If
    Next m
Next Sh**

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Sh.Protect Password:="1"


First step, remove On Error Resume Next

Sh.Range(Columns(6, m)) ---> Sh.Cells(6, m).Value
